# How to show a custom variable from Laravel into Sweet Alert message

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, sweetalert, sweetalert2

I'm working with Laravel v8 and Sweet Alert v2 and I wanted to show a popup message when the user clicks on the **Delete** button.

So I coded this:

```
$(document).on('click', '#btn-submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    let form = $(this).parents('form');
    Swal.fire({
        title: "Confrimation!",
        text: "Are you sure you want to delete [this] user",
        type: "warning",
        allowEscapeKey: false,
        allowOutsideClick: false,
        showCancelButton: true,
        confirmButtonColor: "#DD6B55",
        confirmButtonText: "Yes",
        cancelButtonText: "No",
        showLoaderOnConfirm: true,
        closeOnConfirm: false
    }).then((isConfirm) => {
        if (isConfirm.value === true) {
            document.getElementById("delForm").submit();
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    });
});
```

So this works fine and whenever I click on **Delete** button for a user, a popup message comes up and requires me to confirm or cancel the process.

But I wanted to show the username as well in the `text` property of Swal (replace it with `[this]`).

So the final `text` would be something like this:

**`Are you sure you want to delete {{ $user->name }} user`**

Here is the form:

```
<div class="card-body table-responsive p-0">
    <table class="table table-hover">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <th>User ID</th>
                <th>User Name</th>
                <th>Actions</th>
            </tr>
            @if($users->count() != 0)
                @foreach($users as $user)
                <tr>
                    <td>{{ $user->id }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $user->name }}</td>
                    @if($user->isSameUser($user->id))
                        <td class="d-flex">
                            <div class="btn-group">
                                <form id="delForm" action="{{ route('admin.users.destroy' , ['user' => $user->id]) }}" method="POST">
                                    @csrf
                                    @method('DELETE')
                                    <input id="btn-submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-orange ml-1" value="Delete"></input>
                                </form>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    @endif
                </tr>
                @endforeach
            @else
                <td colspan="10" class="text-center">Nothing to show!</td>
            @endif
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

But don't know how to send the username (`{{ $user->name }}`) to the sweet alert message in order to show it in the text of `Swal`.

In fact, I tried testing this:

```
Swal.fire({
                title: "Attention!",
                text: "{!! isset($user) ? json_decode($user->id) : '' !!}",
                ...
```

But didn't output anything, meaning that `$user` is not defined!

So what's going wrong here? How can I get the data from Laravel and show it on Sweet Alert popup message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the user name to submit the input with data attribute

```
<input id="btn-submit" type="submit" data-name="{{ $user->name }}" class="btn btn-sm btn-orange ml-1" value="Delete" />
```

in submit function, you get the value of data attribute like:

```
$(document).on('click', '#btn-submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    let name = $(this).data('name');
    Swal.fire({
        title: "Confrimation!",
        text: `Are you sure you want to delete ${name} user`,
...
```

Or you can pass PHP variable to javascript variable Inside submit function listener

```
let name = "{{ $user->name }}"
```

Answer (score 0):

try storing value of php variable into javascript variable

```
<script>
var messageTxt = "<?= isset($user) ? json_decode($user->id) : '' ?>"
Swal.fire({
                title: "Attention!",
                text: messageTxt,
})
</script>
```